# Expectation conditional on indicator function

Tags: probability-theory

Let T and K be dependent continuous random variables, and note the Indicator function as I{.}:

Is it correct to say that $E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]=E[T|T>t,K<k]$? Is that a property of the Indicator function?

Comment: No, because the left-most is a random variable, the right-most is a number. The first is the conditional expectation of $T$ conditioned on the sigma-field generated by $\{T>t,K<k\}$. To see their relation, see e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287450/25632)

Comment: @StefanHansen Oh, I missed your comment. Perhaps, it's better if I delete my answer (which happened to be almost identical) and you post your's as an answer.

Comment: @Ilya: The answer is yours, I just gave the appropriate link. Go ahead and undelete :)

Comment: Thanks! That means I have a problem with something else... Maybe I should open another question? I was asking this question because I know that $E[T \text{ x } I\{T>t,K<k\}]=E[T|T>t,K<k]Pr[T>a,k<b]$ I was trying to prove it by:
$E[T \text{ x } I\{T>t,K<k\}]\\
=E[I\{T>t,K<k\}E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]]\\
=E[I\{T>t,K<k\}]E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]\\
=Pr[T>a,K<k]E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]
=Pr[T>a,k<b]E[T|T>a,k<b]
$.\\ But I see now the last step is not actually true...

Comment: Yes, you should post this as a new question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any measurable $A$ you have $\mathsf E[\cdot|1_A] = \mathsf E[\cdot|\sigma(A)]$ where $\sigma(A)$ is given by
$$
  \sigma(A) = \{\emptyset,\Omega,A,A^c\}.
$$
For the relation between this object and the conditional expectation you thought of, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287440/how-is-pa-defined-from-p-mathcalb/287450#287450).