# Proof of truncated expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I want to prove that $E[T \times I\{T>t,K<k\}]=E[T|T>t,K<k]\Pr[T>t,K<k]$, where $T$ and $K$ are continuous random variables and $I{}$ is the indicator function.

I was trying to prove this result, as follows:
$$E[T \times I\{T>t,K<k\}]\\[8pt]
=E[I\{T>t,K<k\}E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]]\\[8pt]
=E[I\{T>t,K<k\}]E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]\\[8pt]
=\Pr[T>t,K<k]E[T|I\{T>t,K<k\}]\\[8pt]
=\Pr[T>t,K<k]E[T|T>t,K<k]
$$

I know my proof is wrong (on a previous post -[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289664/expectation-conditional-on-indicator-function#comment631474_289664)- it was noted that the last step does not follow).

Comment: I changed $T\text{ x }I$ to $T\times I$ in two places in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\{T>t,K<k\}$ and $I_A$ denote the indicator function of $A$. Note that on the set $A$ we have that $E[T\mid I_A]$ and $E[T\mid A]$ are identical (according to Ilya's answer), i.e.
$$
E[T\mid I_A]\cdot I_A=E[T\mid A]\cdot I_A
$$
and hence your second line becomes 
$$
E\big[I_A\cdot E[T\mid I_A]\big]=E\big[I_A\cdot E[T\mid A]\big].
$$
But $E[T\mid A]$ is just a number and so 
$$
E\big[I_A\cdot E[T\mid A]\big]=E[T\mid A]E[I_A]=E[T\mid A]P(A).
$$

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out!

Comment: You're welcome.